Why Mutpy is not genrating mutant.text file?

calculator.py

def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


test_calculator.py

from unittest import TestCase
from calculator import mul

class CalculatorTest(TestCase):

    def test_mul(self):
        self.assertEqual(mul(2, 2), 4)

When I hit the below command:
$ python.exe "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\mut.py" --target calculator --unit-test test_calculator -m

It is not generating the mutant.txt file.
